# YARD - ActiveSupport::Concern#included 内の YARD ドキュメントの書き方

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Railsのプロジェクトで `ActiveSupport::Concern#included` 内のコードのドキュメントを書こうとすると、YARD側がコメントを認識してくれず、ドキュメントの生成が行えません。

例えば下記のようなコードです。

```
module Product::Scopes
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do

    # @!method odd
    #   奇数のid の商品を返す
    #   @!scope class
    scope :odd, -> { where('products.id%2=1') }
  end
end
```

上記のコードで、YARD を実行すると `#odd` は一切認識されず、白紙のページが表示されてしまいます。

色々試してみましたが、上手な回避方法が見当たりませんでした。#included 外に書けばなんとか出来ますが、それではそもそもソースコード内にドキュメントを書いている意味があまりなくなってしまいます。

何かいい感じの回避策などがありましたら、ご教授下さい。よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry if I am not allowed to post here as I do not speak Japanese, but this question is one of the first results to the search "ruby yard activesupport concern". As I needed a solution for the same problem as @Hazi, I figured it would make sense to post the one I have finally developed myself:

https://github.com/digitalcuisine/yard-activesupport-concern

This YARD plugin adds support for ActiveSupport::Concern modules by instructing YARD to parse blocks given to `included` and `class_methods` calls.